# Javascript: Brackets after an array in braces

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've just run into a piece of code I've never seen before, and can't find an explanation anywhere online:

```
function segColor(c) {
    return {
        red: "#FF0000",
        green: "#00ff00",
        blue: "#0000ff"
    }[c];
}
```

What operation is being done to the function parameter c? What does {array}[val] do in javascript? Searching for "brackets after braces" doesn't really reveal a lot.

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object. `[]` on an object is a property selector.

Comment: _What operation is being done to the function parameter c?_ Accessing object's property

Comment: You are accessing an object's property, try to do: `segColor("green");`. you are basically using a function to access to an object's property through the function's parameter.

Comment: It's also a terribly unclear and unintiutive way of doing what it does.

Comment: @j08691 I wouldn't say so, you just need to know how objects work.

Comment: @Jan - I'm pretty sure I'm OK with JS objects and even *I* don't like this method. And for those that aren't familiar with the syntax it's confusing, hence this question.

Comment: @Jan And see the `[c]` at the end. No problem for few lines of code, but easily confusing for many. "So here it's returning some huge object, huh? *scroll scroll scroll* Ah, wait, no, it's a decision table." This is like a branch prediction fail for the brain.

Comment: @j08691 I meant the collective you, not you specifically. Sure, it's a bit of an exploit of the property selector, but if you know what that is it's instantly readable. And maybe OP would never have learnt about it if they hadn't seen this use, so... I dunno, that people don't know the syntax of a language doesn't strike me as a reason not to code a certain way.

Comment: @Siguza For a huge hard-coded object, yeah of course. You should generelly try to keep your logic as closely knit as possible. But this isn't a huge object. And if you have  a huge hard-coded object, then your problem might be that you have a huge hard-coded object, not this notation.

Comment: @Jan Alright, can't disagree with that.

Comment: And you could just as well then do for example `var myHugeObject = {/* .... */}; return myHugeObject[c];` which would make it more intuitive and readable.

Comment: Just noting that this code was from an example provided by the D3 graphing resource - it's not mine! I'll keep your arguments in mind before implementing it in my own code, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c` is being used as a property accessor to the object. The function is being used as a static mapper to retrieve the corresponding value for a color word

```js
function segColor(c) {
    return {
        red: "#FF0000",
        green: "#00ff00",
        blue: "#0000ff"
    }[c];
}

console.log(segColor('green'));
```